# Streaming 2 local and some remote players audio issue

Tags: audio, streaming, audio-recording, microphone

I am trying to set up for streaming. Here is what i want to accomplish. I will be the only one streaming video and streaming from the same computer i am playing on. I have a mixer attached to my computer. My wife has a microphone attached to the mixer so that her audio is on the stream. I have some remote players that are going to be on the stream too. So we are using Teamspeak, so everyone's audio is on the stream. My wife and i have to use headphones. Now the problem, i need to be able to hear my wife without her echoing in the stream.

Currently i have her locally muted in Teamspeak. She is not echoing in the stream, but i can't hear her, because i have my headphones on. What can i do to set this up so i can hear everyone, including my wife, with no echo. My wife needs to come through on the stream with the microphone that is attached to the mixer. Not the Teamspeak microphone.

Here is my current set up.

My computer is streaming the content.
My computer has a mixer attached to it.
My computer has a microphone attached to the mixer.
Her computer has a microphone attached to the mixer and a separate microphone used for Teamspeak.
My computer is in Teamspeak.
Her computer is in Teamspeak.
Other people are in Teamspeak.
My computer has "her" locally muted in Teamspeak.

I can't her her, because of headphones and i need to hear her without her echoing in the stream.

Would VAC(virtual audio cable) help me? What do i need to do to solve this issue.

Thanks